# "Isekai" Manga where the main character got back to earth after saving the previous world, but he realised that humans need to be exterminated

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The main character was a guy with not so long black hair, at around the age range between teen and adult, after he saved the world he got transported back to earth with his powers, not long after that a mugger/gangster came up to him and he decided that he would kill every human or at least the bad ones, he uses what I assume is a recall spell to get his hammer and kills said gangster in the street. That all I remember as I only read the first few chapters.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember where and when you read this?

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: Is the title "After returning from the other world, I decided to kill everyone"? Based on isekai manga naming conventions and plot subtlety, this seems like a good guess.

Comment: I think I've found it, but can you confirm some differences: 1. Is the guy definitely the main character, or a villain with plenty of backstory in the first chapter? 2. Definitely a hammer, or a giant, impractical anime sword?

Comment: @qazmlpok If you think you've found it, post an answer.  Even if it isn't what OP is asking about, A) they will be able to say what the differences are, helping other people looking, B) it stops other people from trying to suggest the same thing, and C) it will help other users in future, who *were* looking for that story but found this question while searching.

Comment: @Chronocidal I prefer to avoid posting answers unless I'm reasonably certain they're correct. While there are positives to maybe-correct answers, there's also a negative: it makes it look like the question is already solved. Any answer will remove it from an "unanswered questions" search, and there's no way for the asker to mark an answer explicitly incorrect. That said, if the asker doesn't comment within a day I will just assume it's right and post it.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely *[The Warrior Returns](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-warrior-returns)*. It is available on [Webtoons](https://www.webtoons.com/en/action/the-warrior-returns/list?title_no=3265).

> **After saving one world**, warrior Minsu Kim returns to Earth only to find that he’s lost everything... so he decides to **destroy the world** he used to call home. In his rampage, he kills teenager Jeongsu Park and his family. But instead of dying normally, Jeongsu is transported to another world, where he finds that he's now a warrior himself. After killing the demon king of this alternate world and honing his skills as a warrior, Jeongsu returns to earth, hell-bent on revenge against Minsu.

[image: Cover image]

Minsu Kim is likely the person described in the question, shown on the cover above, however he is not the protagonist. The entire first chapter is about him, but it's more of a villain backstory. The description of his hairstyle and age are a match, and he is someone that went to another world, saved it, and returned.

The scene with the "mugger" occurs near the end of the first chapter; Minsu decides that every other human should be as miserable as him, and starts killing people indiscriminately. He starts with a jerk he randomly bumped into that started harassing him. He summons a giant sword and instantly kills him, then starts destroying the city.

[image: Giant sword killing a person]