# Manga where the main character's family were destroyed and their souls put into an artifact

Tags: story-identification, manga, cultivation

I'm looking for a manga that was on the late mangatx.com site. In this manga, the main character's family was killed by a powerful cultivator and their souls, if I remember correctly, were used to make an artifact. When he joined a sect to get stronger to (sic) was later entirely destroyed and he at one point ended up on another continent or dimension world. The only clue I have is that, on the cover picture, the main character was wearing a red shirt and he had one wing.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?

Comment: While it's not what you're asking about, what you're describing sounds remarkably like Elena of Avalor (sans the male protagonist and it being manga). Not sure what a cultivator is offhand. Okay, I looked it up. I'm familiar with those. EOA is a little like that (but not super intensely).

Answer (score 1):

Might this be *[The Warrior Returns](https://www.webtoons.com/en/action/the-warrior-returns/)* as per [Manhwa where the main character is sent to another world after his family is killed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/277850/manhwa-where-the-main-character-is-sent-to-another-world-after-his-family-is-kil)?

> After saving one world, warrior Minsu Kim returns to Earth only to find that he’s lost everything... so he decides to destroy the world he used to call home. In his rampage, he kills teenager Jeongsu Park and his family. But instead of dying normally, Jeongsu is transported to another world, where he finds that he's now a warrior himself. After killing the demon king of this alternate world and honing his skills as a warrior, Jeongsu returns to earth, hell-bent on revenge against Minsu.

Not matching, while the cover does show him in red, there isn't one wing.

[image: Front cover of The Warrior Returns]

Comment: I read it on mangatx.com between 5-6 years ago but I do remember another thing when the Mc confronted the guy who killed his family he was about to be killed but some portal or wormhole open right behind him and he died while getting sucked into it because it wasn’t stable but his soul survived and while inside he possessed someone else body who had died not too long ago. Another thing was that in this universe there are these beads that can help cultivate faster than most people I believe the one the mc had gave him pills